# Get width of Entry in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How do I get the width of an Entry view in Xamarin.Forms? I'm trying to make an entry in iOS look like the default entry in Android (the one with the line underneath).

Custom Renderer:

```
void SetBorderWidth(Controls.Entry control)
{
    Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
    var myBox = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 40, <INSERT WIDTH HERE>, 1));
    myBox.BackgroundColor = control.BorderColor.ToUIColor();
    Control.AddSubview(myBox);
}
```

Whenever I try to insert either control.Width, control.WidthRequest, control.MinimumWidthRequest nothing happens. But if I put a number the line underneath suddenly shows.

Additionally when I print out the width and widthrequest they have a value of -1.

Comment: When are you calling `SetBorderWidth`?

Comment: Inside `protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your iOS Entry renderer, override the `Draw` method and use the `CGRect` provided as the current `Frame` size of the `UITextField`, since this method can be called multiple times (screen rotations, resizes, etc... Save your `UIView` after its initial creation and just update its `Frame`.

Something like (I do not have my personal code with me, but this should be "close"):

```
UIView myBox;
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    switch (myBox)
    {
        case null:
            myBox = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 40, rect.Width, 1));
            Control.AddSubview(myBox);
            break;
        default:
            myBox.Frame = new CGRect(0, 40, rect.Width, 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the width from the `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` element and not override the `Draw` method?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `Draw`? This is the native draw routine of any UIView and the CGRect provided is the most current Frame size. In the `OnElementChanged` the width is not defined as the Form's layout engine has not completed and thus the native controls typically has a width/height of zero.

Comment: I would like to not override too much stuff and rely more on Xamarin.Forms if possible. I have already resolved this thanks to what you said that the native controls typically have a width/height of zero before the Form's layout engine completes its process.

So I used the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method and got the width after it has been assigned a non-zero width by the Form's layout engine.

Comment: @iamlawrencev OnElementPropertyChanged is just another override, same as Draw and slightly slower are you have to do a string comparison for the prop name.... but remember the OnElementPropertyChanged for `Width` can and will get called multiple times just like `Draw` so make sure you are not just creating a new UIView every time....